# "The phone auth credential was created with an empty verification ID" - Firebase SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I did phone authentication with firebase, but when I enter the verification code , I get an error
"The phone auth credential was created with an empty verification ID"

Screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtEwp.jpg)

Code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class OTPViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var number: String = ""
    @Published var code: String = ""
    
    @Published var otpText: String = ""
    @Published var otpFields: [String] = Array(repeating: "", count: 6)
    
    @Published var showAlert: Bool = false
    @Published var errorMsg: String = ""
    @Published var verificationCode: String = ""
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = false
    @Published var navigationTag: String?
    
    @AppStorage("log_status") var log_status = false
    
    func sendOTP()async{
        if isLoading{return}
        do{
            isLoading = true
            let result = try await
            PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber("+\(code)\(number)", uiDelegate: nil)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.isLoading = false
                self.verificationCode = result
                self.navigationTag = "VERIFICATION"
            }
        }
        catch{
            handleError(error: error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func handleError(error: String){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.isLoading = false
            self.errorMsg = error
            self.showAlert.toggle()
        }
    }
    
    func verifyOTP()async{
        do{
            isLoading = true
            let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationCode, verificationCode: otpText)
            let _ = try await Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {[self] in
                isLoading = false
                log_status = true
            }
        }
        catch{
            handleError(error: error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried add this, before isLoading = true on the verifyOtp Method.

```
otpText = otpFields.reduce("") { partialResult, value in
   partialResult + value
}
```

But still not worked

Comment: It seems like the `verificationCode` you provide to `PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID, verificationCode)` is empty. Have you confirmed that it's not the case?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what I should do

Comment: place a `print(verificationCode)` just before you call `PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, here's the solution:

1. In your `sendOTP()` function after `self.verificationCode = result` add `UserDefaults.standard.set(self.verificationCode, forKey: "authVerificationID")`
2. In your `verifyOTP()` function after `isLoading = true` add `let verificationCode = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authVerificationID") ?? ""`

The point was that you needed to save your verification ID and then retrieve it to ensure that it is still valid if your app is terminated before the user completes the sign-in flow. See clause 3.3 of the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth?authuser=0#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone).